# How to generate monsters/weapons of a specific level?

Tags: algorithm, random

### Background

Assume that we have a game where monsters and weapons are generated "randomly".

A **weapon** could be defined like this:

- type: axe (1.2) / sword (1.4) / spear (1) / club (0.7)
- range: 1 - 3
- magic: ice (10) / fire (10) / none (1)
- state: sharp (2) / normal (1) / dull (0.5)

Some of these values could have dependencies (e.g. type and range).

Using a random generator we could get for example a *dull Axe of Fire (range 2)*. Then we could have a formula that calculates the **level** of this weapon. Example formula:

```
level = floor(type * range * magic * state)
```

The *dull Axe of Fire (range 2)* would then have level `floor(1.2 * 2 * 10 * 0.5) = 12`.

Simple, but nice!

We could also have a **world** where the player goes deeper and deeper down into the dangerous caves, starting at cave level 1.

### The question

Let's say the player is at cave level 12. (S)he has entered a room where we want to place a weapon in a chest.

**What would be a good algorithm to generate a level 12 weapon?** (or any other level of course)

I.e. we have the level and want to use a level calculation (our simple one, or another more sophisticated) *backwards* to generate good values for the different elements of the weapon.

*Minor or major changes to the definition of a weapon can be made to facilitate a better solution.*

#### EDIT:

It seems like [High Performance Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/44309/high-performance-mark)'s solution is the best where there are a reasonably limited set of combinations. If not, or if we have continuous values and an "unlimited" set of combinations, one of the other answers might be better suited. I say "might" since maybe a lookup table could be used even in a continuous version for a subset of the values to pick a good starting point and then one could add a small random delta to fill in.

Example: range is continuous between 10 and 200. The lookup table contains values (10, 20, 30, ..., 190, 200). The algorithm picks 110 for range and then adds random(-5.0, 5.0) to it for a final value of, say, 108.72. Then the final level of the weapon would be close enough to the desired value to do. How does that sound?

Comment: It sounds like a generalized subset sum problem (take log of the parameters and send their magnitudes to infinity).

Comment: You could ask this question on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ to see if you get better answers.

Comment: @Gilbert Le Blanc: I've already gotten some pretty good answers, but is it possible to move the question, or should I just ask it again over there?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear.  You don't have to move your question.  I was pointing out another game developer resource for you to use if you wish.

Comment: @Gilbert Le Blanc: Sorry if *I* didn't sound thankful. Thanks for your suggestion!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have, say, 5 choices each of type, range, magic and state then you have 5^4 choices of weapon.  This is quite a small number and you could easily store them all in a lookup table, indexed on the level of weapons.  When you want a random level 12 weapon, you choose uniformly from the available level 12 weapons.

Comment: It feels like cheating, but I can not find a fault with your solution unless there are a lot of options or continuous values. As the subject of my question implies, I was thinking of monster generation too, and in that case there might be more values (e.g. strength: 1-20, intelligence: 1-20, and so on). It might be doable anyway of course, memory is cheap :)

Answer (score 2):

If the formula for calculating the level of the weapon is simple as in this case, you may think of choosing the level randomly, and then calculate the parameters of the weapon by repeatingly divide the level by random factors.

For instance, you have the level 12. Then you randomly generate a weapon type. You get spear (1.0) and do 12/1.0 = 12. Then you randomly choose the magic and you get fire (10). Then you have 12 /10 = 1.2. You go on until you have only one parameter to set and eventually you choose that value. For a better balanced system you may decide to reorder the parameter to guess and/or the probability of the random generators depending on the current values of your guess.

Comment: Can you clarify your solution with an example?

Comment: @Peter Jaric added an example

Answer (score 2):

Based on the element you pick in the first list, what are the maximum and minimum level values you can achieve? For instance, for a club, you can achieve any level between `floor(0.7 * 1 * 1 * 0.5) = 0` and `floor(0.7 * 3 * 10 * 2) = 43`. So, if you were looking for level 44 weapon, you should never pick a club. This helps you restrict the set of acceptable choices in the first list.

These min-max values can be computed on the fly for a simple monotonous function like this one, but it can also be pre-computed in advance if the level function is too complex.

Repeat the process for the other lists, ending with a list that allows continuous values, such as damage (being continuous lets you pick a fudge value that selects the appropriate level).

For instance, looking for a level-12 weapon, one would pick randomly an axe (min:0, max:72), pick randomly "of fire" (min: 6, max: 72), eliminate "sharp" (min:24, max:72), pick randomly "dull" (min:6, max:18), and then use a fudge value of 2 = 12/6 for the range.

Comment: To make sure I understand this correctly: are you saying that I should use the range (in this case) or damage (if I had that value) to manipulate the calculation to get the desired level? That sounds promising, but are you sure that won't unbalance the weapons in some direction? I am thinking of a a lot of level 1 weapons of fire or ice (range 2cm). That wasn't possible in my example, but maybe you get what I mean.

Comment: Yes. The only requirement is that the range/damage/whatever is a *continuous* value, so that you could have a range of 1.31545 if you really needed to. However, keep in mind that this continuous value also has a minimum and maximum, like the others, and these values are taken into account to eliminate elements in the other lists so that, in the end, the algorithm ensures that no value below the minimum (or above the maximum) will *ever* be picked.